# Нужен lock для очередей проверок

Tags: предложение, очередь-проверок

Нередко, когда проверяю сообщения через очередь проверок, не успеваю подтвердить результат. Оказывается, что кто-то уже успел проверить это сообщение до меня — либо раньше начал, либо потратил меньше времени. А мое время оказывается потраченным впустую.

Все это побуждает меня к тому, чтобы проверять быстрее и менее внимательно. Вчитываться в вопрос несколько минут я уж точно не могу. Это понижает качество проверок. Наверняка и другие участники сталкиваются с тем же.

Хочу чтобы когда я открываю страницу проверки, система резервировала ее для меня на некоторое время, например 3 или 5 минут. Должно быть фиксированное количество "мест", каждое из которых может занять один проверяющий.

Кстати, это наверняка даже ускорит проработку очередей, так как исключатся потери времени на уже завершенные проверки.

Comment: Ну или хотя бы уменьшить вероятность коллизии, раздавая вопросы на проверку по кругу.

Comment: там есть лок. по крайней мере у меня проверку "выхватывали" из рук всего пару раз.

Comment: @PashaPash: у меня дважды сегодня выхватили за короткий промежуток времени. Подозреваю, что нет лока.

Comment: @PashaPash Блокировка есть при правке из очереди, вроде. В остальных случаях кто успел, тот и съел.